# $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $a + b = 2$ and $|a|<|b|$. Show that $1 \in ]|a|,|b|[ \iff ab \in ]-3,1[$

Tags: analysis

We have:

$|a|<1<|b| \iff |a|+|b| < 1 + |b| < 2|b|$

$\iff (|a|+|b|)² < (1+|b|)² < 4|b|² $

$ \iff|a|² + 2|a||b| + |b|² < 1 + 2|b| + |b|² < 4|b|²$

$ \iff 2|a||b| < 1 + 2|b| - |a|² < 3|b|² - |a|² $

I don't see how to proceed to get $ab \in ]-3,1[$

Thank you.

Comment: @LazyLee I have just edited it. We have $1 \in ]|a|,|b|[ \iff |a| < 1 < |b|$. We can't take $ a = -1$/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We consider the function $f(a) = a(2 - a) = ab $

$\forall a \in (-1,1): f'(a) = 2(1 - a) > 0 $

$ f(-1) < f(a) < f(1)  \iff  -3 < ab < 1$

Answer (score 0):

Tip: Find other way.

a+b=2 implies a=2-b. Hence, |a|<|b| is equivalent to |2-b|<|b|. This implies b>1, so, a<1 (by a+b=2). Therefore, $|b|=b$.

Suppose $1\in(|a|,|b|)$. $b>1$ is not a problem, but it is neccesary $a\in(-1,1)$, hence... the rest for you ;).

Comment: $-1 < a < 1 \iff -b < ab < b \implies - 1 < ab < b \implies -3 < ab < b $ ? 

That is not equivalent to: $-3 < ab < 1 $. 

We have: $-1 < a < 1 $ and $ 1 < b = 2 - a < 3$. But $- 3 < ab < 3$ ? 

Thank you for your help.